# pass a Buffer object into imagemagick library correctly

Tags: node.js, stream, request, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I'm writing an application to leverage [this library](https://github.com/yourdeveloper/node-imagemagick) into a general purpose image resizing utility

Have it working with local files, attempting to update it with http streams.

Looks like in theory its `resize` wrapper will take a `srcData` object, which I assume can be a Buffer object, but my app is choking.

Here's a simplified version:

```
im = require('imagemagick')
request = require('request')

sampleImage = "http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0504stolze/test_1.jpg"

request.get(sampleImage, (err, res, body) ->

    taskHash = {
        srcPath: "-"
        srcData: body
        dstPath: "-"
        height: 100
    }

    callback = (err, stdout, stderr)->
        if err
            console.error(err)
            process.exit(1)
        console.log(stdout)

    im.resize(taskHash, callback)

)
```

This is erroring out:

```
{ [Error: Command failed: convert: no decode delegate for this image format `/var/tmp/magick-37627o1E7kWz7yGaf' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/555.
convert: no images defined `-' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3144.
] timedOut: false, killed: false, code: 1, signal: null }
```

which makes me think that it's having trouble identifying the Buffer as a a jpg object. But even if I explicitly declare the buffer as a jpg in the options hash, it still gives me the same error:

```
taskHash = {
    srcPath: "-"
    srcData: body
    dstPath: "-"
    format: 'jpg'
    height: 100
}
```

Not sure how to pass this in as a correct Buffer object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is saying that it doesn't know the format of the image. According to [the ImageMagic docs](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php), you can specify the format in the `srcPath` argument, such as `gif:-`.

The best way to find the format of the HTTP response is in the `Content-Type` header, as it may not be a part of the url.

Comment: The `srcPath` prefix worked, I guess that the `format` option only designates output.